# Connection suffers from "packet loss" and trace route

Tags: isp, traceroute, packet, packet-loss

My internet connection has been suffering from packet loss for weeks and I'm trying to find where it is happening. It can go up to 35% packet loss, which is terrible and it's really bad when playing online.

So I tried a trace route to Google.com

[**Here are the results**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO3J2.jpg)

Tried many times, and it is always timing out or failing multiple times with a * on the very first step, which is my ISP right?

What is the first fully "timed out" line? Why no IP showing up? It is actually the second line which is a second try?

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `*` only means, that this step doesn't respond to ICMP `echo-request` messages, which is not uncommon with home or "last mile" routers. It does not indicate packet loss at this step, **unless** it sometimes responds and sometimes doesn't.

The most likely reason for packet loss on a home internet connection is upstream overload - you first need to confirm the packet loss, when no upstream activity (apart from your test) at all is running. Best possibility is to disconnect all other devices than your test machine.

Comment: Yes my router has been reset, I only have 1 desktop computer connected to it with RJ45 cable. Packet loss is also happening when testing with wifi, so it's not a cable defect from my home. I'm trying to pinpoint the problem and help my ISP isolate the issue, because when I call the callcenter, they are goofs and mostly have no clue...

It there anything else I can try  to find where the issue is occuring ? Maybe ping 213.245.255.241 (which is the first step where timing out happens, and after checking, is definitly a server owned by my ISP)?

Comment: So I used WinMTR to ping my first ISP's server ( 213.245.255.241 ) https://imgur.com/QisV2Y0

There is packet loss but before it, you can see a weird line "no response from host", which doesn't have an IP adress, what could it be?

Comment: As stated in the answer that will be an ISP device that does not respond to pings.

Answer (score 0):

When do you notice the internet connection is bad? Is there anything specific you are doing when this happens?
Does it get better or worst in the morning, afternoon, evening, or at night? 
Does it happen often, every time, at random times, or is it intermittent?
Have you provided your ISP with the IP address that's giving the error?
How do you know the IP address belongs to your internet provider?

When I pinged 213.245.255.241, the host name is col1rj-ge-1-1-5.200.numericable.net.

The ping times out after IP address 80.231.153.206 (3 hops) and then it reaches 213.245.255.241

Comment: Complete route to google.com : https://imgur.com/cagxLfl

All knots suffer from packet loss, is it a common thing? There is still this 1st line after my local adress which I can't explain, and seems weird, also 100% packet loss there. Is this an ISP server which could be offline or something like this? I'm clueless.

For the record, I live in Paris, France, and since the coronavirus outbreak and the urge to work from home, my connection went to pieces. I never had any issue before, but now, it is terrible. Maybe ISP servers are overloaded? But this happens continuously, even on weekends...

Comment: I understand your concern as I also work from home in the US. You may be able to let your manager know the issue you are having with your ISP just so they are aware and it does't cause any issues with your job. You can also let your ISP know and they may have a different plan you can use during this pandemic.